# NullPointerException when getting GoogleMap from MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, mapfragment

null pointer exception when getting android google maps  where is the error ?

MapActivity.java :

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1))
           .getMap();

    Marker marker=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_CITY).title("").visible(true));
    marker.setDraggable(true);


}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: You can see the line number in LogCat.. so you tell me..

Comment: Post your logcat. Is your Activity extends with Activity or FragmentActivity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should simply check by

```
if (map != null) {
   Marker marker=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_CITY).title("").visible(true));
marker.setDraggable(true);
}
```

Must be sure that if your minimum SDK version is < 12 then you must use

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

and if it is >=12 then you should use this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` like:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();
```